# Is Cardano working on any solutions to work out disputes between parties?

Tags: smart-contract

I know dispute resolution within smart contracts (when used as a method of transaction) is not a simple issue. Is Cardano working through any innovative solutions to work out disputes between two parties?
Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the questions about the future of Cardano can't be effectively addressed on this site and would be better addressed directly to the Cardano Team on their [forum](https://forum.cardano.org/). This site is not operated by the Cardano organization.

Comment: I am developing a conflict resolution platform on Cardano right now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little torn here about whether the question will attract opinion-based responses. If answered with facts only then a smart contract has already defined rules, if they are fulfilled there is no room for dispute. Means: Either everyone agrees to these rules or no contract is concluded.

Of course, these results may not meet the expectations of the contractual partner, but this is fundamentally not the problem of smart contracts and to discuss this Stack Exchange is not the right place. For such open questions and extensive discussions, e.g. forum.cardano.org would be a good place.